# Image break in sending HTML email with text over image

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have an image cropped in photoshop and generated the HTML! I need to insert a text inside the second image and send it in the body of the email, everything works almost perfectly, if the text was not to the left of the image and not inside as I need it !!

I have the following code:

```
'<tr>'+
    '<td>'+
        '<img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1G90igOahW8OW9Hls-cdUYHWMoE1p-mWy" width="80" height="37"  border="0"  style="display:block" alt=""></td>'+
        //'<div class="texto">'+
          //'<i id="spaceText" class="fas fa-search"></i>'+dados[i][0]+'</td>'+
        //'</div>'+
     '<td>'+
```

Which is generating the following: 
[image: Obtained]

And this is what I need:
[image: Wanted]

Below is a demo sheet with complete code for better understanding:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L3gJEkxf43FHiIpKpq9vdLKyQSvOzXJwDyMM8oot10s/edit?usp=sharing

I am very grateful that you can help me and respond with details, as my knowledge is small in scripts and HTML

Comment: Rich HTML email templates are an _absolute pain_ in the ass.  If this problem absolutely requires a solution I would look into Litmus and [campaignmonitor](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/).

Comment: I don't understand almost anything about code, could you help me to solve this if possible? I need to send this through google spreadsheets and apparently it doesn't accept CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you have formatting issues: learn how to apply css in html

- Take a look on : [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout), [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox), [margins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin), etc..

> If you want to implement css inside html tags use **style attribute**

- Like `<td style="background-color:grey">`

> You are using **v8** in your Apps Script project, which means you can use [Modern ECMAScript syntax](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime)

- In your example you could use backtick character **`**:

```
var mensagem =`
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>VLNP</title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    </head>
...
    </head>
  </html>`;
```

instead of

```
     var mensagem = 

'<html>'+
'<head>'+
'<title>VLNP</title>'+
'<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">'+
'</head>'+
...
'</body>'+
'</html>'
```

### Answer

I run this code and it didn't give me any errors, just change `email` value with your email

```
function Envia_VLNP_Capa_NOK() { 

  var linhaINICIAL = 2; 
  var colunaENVIO = 2;  
  var colunaSTATUS = 3;
  var textoCONDICAO = "NOK";
  var textoENVIADO = "ENVIADO"
  var blob = 3

  var aba = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Teste"); 
  var intervalo = aba.getRange(linhaINICIAL,1,aba.getLastRow()-linhaINICIAL+1,colunaSTATUS);
  var dados = intervalo.getValues();
  var enviou = false;
  var email,assunto,mensagem;


  for (var i=0; i<dados.length; ++i) {

   {muteHttpExceptions: true};

    if((dados[i][colunaENVIO-1]==textoCONDICAO) && (dados[i][colunaSTATUS-1]!=textoENVIADO)){

    var email    =  "YOUR EMAIL HERE";

     assunto = "Email"; //ASSUNTO DO EMAIL

     var mensagem =`
<html>

<head>
  <title>VLNP</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
  <div id="centro" align="center">
    <table id="Tabela_01" width="821" height="519" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
          <a href=""><img src="" width="240" height="104" border="0" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="5"><img src="" width="581" height="104" border="0" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1G90igOahW8OW9Hls-cdUYHWMoE1p-mWy" width="80" height="37" border="0" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
        <td><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1qB6NKacg9bPtR9uwxIPm7ybE7_nUG_rx" width="160" height="37" border="0" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
        <td><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1XPPcFrXPiZPqU6pIPPmBrC6mQiRUebfd" width="114" height="37" border="0" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
        <td><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1L2UKyJrFoeRJeYYmZPnfOs_Cj_nlI0-0" width="71" height="37" border="0" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="2"><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1c1FRGq7M5QSVLwo-irV-SvIY-TzEAnpe" width="206" height="37" border="0" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
        <td><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1VR8R2zqjW5_9uOraU1hy-e5TVDsHBqLA" width="190" height="37" border="0" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1Rc4DgamoemPTaNCq4Icw4msSmiNMErln" width="80" height="37" border="0" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
        <td><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1_yGNsXPM9bYbsu-QUwTzsMrWPrJSLMyb" width="160" height="37" border="0" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
        <td><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1553JARZd5XhUZe2zxZcAtnznL2myXem1" width="114" height="37" border="0" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
        <td><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1wLoIIWtbXxyocfN3TNK2AYMLUCXNshvZ" width="71" height="37" border="0" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="2"><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1Yaz_sxIZ7zupZRmOdlDrexsy51MQkqgX" width="206" height="37" border="0" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
        <td><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1bmhrhWo-ebFN7Ghw56bzxoUfrQZBr3pE" width="190" height="37" border="0" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1ypxusUG5JtwqmHWEa5uUa2qNCnZxa_vA" width="240" height="37" border="0" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="2"><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1cvAhxUsNiMRKt64SwZtRYr4LuK8dtV4t" width="185" height="37" border="0" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="2"><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1qCGIFOPX73TYt_itnKv9Zxnw74ws6aRn" width="206" height="37" border="0" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
        <td><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1ya-Km4psgwepbSwqhgPawhv6WK8hv9gG" width="190" height="37" border="0" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1zo5QTk4Ef0S1Zj_dEJISvOmlw5T0_mNM" width="240" height="36" border="0" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="2"><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1ETmwu43LC2OMixSUd8nSC_J3pEmfUX_0" width="185" height="36" border="0" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="2"><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1NVsJ5jZflCtHXCE08piXjFbW_RAn3rCk" width="206" height="36" border="0" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
        <td><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=16Ugp4eo5vzxUYNhYBPXx1ZBpwBVit_I6" width="190" height="36" border="0" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1qP0s8bm_xLO7nlORBbUVg6tA3vu3KCQx" width="240" height="38" border="0" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="3"><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1bSbEosPlKL3WzRgYwwuV8YX-MV4vuVmy" width="321" height="38" border="0" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
        <td><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1WX3JRF_aWuDRx6l7M5o4swDI58TOq8Uo" width="70" height="38" border="0" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
        <td><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1Z4eNiw7PMyiFdtYtdeviQkUmRF4zMbxt" width="190" height="38" border="0" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1PNKJx2ljyqbYnt0i6sguZlcxLa26PzcX" width="240" height="36" border="0" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="5"><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1Y3mOwl06UqV2t0kcDAsi4ygWRffIObr9" width="581" height="36" border="0" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1IS_HgF9fsWjAfEsjwk4wQKaCJFU83bmS" width="240" height="38" border="0" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
        <td><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=11UMdMkm4NutyQYfztzCudXAbudMieR4o" width="114" height="38" border="0" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
        <td><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1kk-6wLUpg4-cWAFrHWx_VCedpBb3517C" width="71" height="38" border="0" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="2"><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1-Zpkl_8JuXvy0f-pvgW2DXETNJtZWU81" width="206" height="38" border="0" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
        <td><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=18-47MkDHGRAAyciEEIk4nuBz2ajKFVKH" width="190" height="38" border="0" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1WcNT6MdC940TAOdJAlhKIZImLMoy9Xls" width="240" height="37" border="0" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="5"><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1A45V8ueSYnHhltTvMOuxGBJy2jfjxsxS" width="581" height="37" border="0" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=11yyLRhuNU8H56_lGKxG-CeHGmvpN_KD6" width="240" height="37" border="0" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="3"><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=18-jQ5v9uq_PuRFpU4oUtLA_1PpSxDVek" width="321" height="37" border="0" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="2"><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1uNGTCwOOb8QRkJOifegAtWaiaianiSfN" width="260" height="37" border="0" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=13WbYtt6edWWln_ZApd29OBYK-BkryAwV" width="240" height="37" border="0" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="5"><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1ZIeQakA13FjeBAIR2rgOimtm1K25JLpi" width="581" height="37" border="0" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1XJKXPZ7bOyNF0l5aafOpUtBJ8iHf9Wrr" width="240" height="36" border="0" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="3"><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1o7HRdKoeDDTBfM1m63J4NjO0ATqDBQ2Z" width="321" height="36" border="0" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
        <td><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1Kyl-Zdrod-0E1swXkd3IKBL90BkGFs5e" width="70" height="36" border="0" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
        <td><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=11HGlHI8_1DNHfnp7tPAAd2a_4ASXrxhh" width="190" height="36" border="0" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="7"><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=142HNTaQedKvTQeQcKIYZnd_gUEdKe0ky" width="821" height="8" border="0" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=131B3o4OVmXBBffATnnBSe7d_jPlhdPes" width="80" height="1" border="0" alt=""></td>
        <td><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=131B3o4OVmXBBffATnnBSe7d_jPlhdPes" width="160" height="1" border="0" alt=""></td>
        <td><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=131B3o4OVmXBBffATnnBSe7d_jPlhdPes" width="114" height="1" border="0" alt=""></td>
        <td><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=131B3o4OVmXBBffATnnBSe7d_jPlhdPes" width="71" height="1" border="0" alt=""></td>
        <td><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=131B3o4OVmXBBffATnnBSe7d_jPlhdPes" width="136" height="1" border="0" alt=""></td>
        <td><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=131B3o4OVmXBBffATnnBSe7d_jPlhdPes" width="70" height="1" border="0" alt=""></td>
        <td><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=131B3o4OVmXBBffATnnBSe7d_jPlhdPes" width="190" height="1" border="0" alt=""></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>`;

    MailApp.sendEmail(email, assunto, mensagem,{ htmlBody: mensagem, image: blob}); // Modified

    aba.getRange(linhaINICIAL+i,colunaSTATUS)
    //.setValue("ENVIADO");
    enviou = true;
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();

    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Hello, @Jeff Rush Thanks for trying to help, but thank you very much if you can help me solve my problem !!

I checked the references, but my knowledge didn't let me apply !!

See that I have two images, I need to make the code display in the body of the emails as in the second image and what I have only gets me the first!

Note that in lines 50,51,52 it is the line that inserts the value of cell A2 in the spreadsheet!

I have two codes in the spreadsheet now, yours and mine!

I will be very grateful if I manage to solve my problem !!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @SidneyCardosodosSantos I would suggest you to use HTML table instead of images, because you can achieve better results with raw table. Regarding your question, I helped you with formatting issue. Consider to accept my answer and ask new questions like **How to create html table**, **How to send html table with sheet data**.